# How to register Vue plugin from files generated by npm build with webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I setup a new Vue project with basic scaffolding using the Vue CLI and Vuetify with tree shaking to eliminate any components I don't need. I'm really only interested in the vendor files that have the Vuetify components (presumably the chunk-vender... files under dist/js and dist/css).

The HTML in my project is including those vendor files, but I don't understand how to register the plugin with Vue. For example, in my app's JS file:

```
Vue.use(vuetify); // where do I get the vuetify plugin object from?
new Vue({...})
```

Just to be clear, I'm not interested in the `app` JS/CSS files generated by the npm build. I'm only using that whole setup so that I can manually cherry pick the Vuetify components I want and create the necessary JS/CSS.

If I include the full-fat Vuetify script/css in my HTML from a CDN e.g.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.3.17/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.3.17/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

...then I can initialize Vuetify in my apps JS like:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#my-app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

...so what I'm hoping to find out is if there is a way to initialize Vuetify using the vendor JS file produced from the Vue CLI build instead of the full CDN version. If I try to use the same initialzation method above when using the vendor build JS file, I get the error `Vuetify is not defined`.

Comment: if you added vuetify using vue cli, then isn't this all done for you? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#vuetify-loader

Comment: I have an existing project that wasn’t created using the cli. I want to integrate some Vuetify components into my project. The only way I know of to get a selection of the components i want is to configure a build using the cli. I have the vendor output files from the build, but I don’t know how to use them. Presumably, the dummy app file created as part of the build is registering the Vuetify plugin somehow, but its minified/mangled so I can’t make any sense of it.

Comment: Why can't you just setup Vuetify tree-shaking in your other non-Vue-CLI project?

Comment: @tony19 I'm not actually using any build tools for my project or package manager. I'm just adding a version number to the Vuetify vendor files produced by the build. Although, as an alternative solution maybe you could provide a example of how to set that up or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a more idiomatic way to create a library with Vue CLI. Your `build` NPM-script should specify the *[library](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library) build type* and an *entry point* that exports a [Vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) (e.g., `src/plugins/vuetify.js`), where only specific Vuetify components are installed.

For example, to create a Vue plugin that installs only [`VApp`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/) (required as root component in Vuetify 2.x), [`VContainer`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/), [`VBtn`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/), and [`VTextField`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/) components:

1. Run these commands to generate a Vue CLI project with the default options:

   ```
   npx @vue/cli create --default my-vuetify
   cd my-vuetify
   ```
2. Run this command from the project's root directory to add Vuetify to the project (and choose *Default* preset at prompt):

   ```
   npx @vue/cli add vuetify
   ```
3. Edit the project's `build` NPM-script in `package.json` to create a library called `MyVuetify` (this will be the global variable set when the library is imported in your `<script>` tag):

   ```js
   // package.json
   {
     "scripts": {
       // BEFORE:
       "build": "vue-cli-service build",

       // AFTER:
       "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name MyVuetify src/plugins/vuetify.js",
     }
   }
   ```
4. In the plugin's entry file, export a `vuetify` function that constructs a new `Vuetify` instance:

   ```js
   // src/plugins/vuetify.js
   import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

   export const vuetify = options => new Vuetify({ ...options })
   ```

   Also export a `plugin` object, containing an `install` function that specifies only the Vuetify components of interest:

   ```js
   // src/plugins/vuetify.js
   import { VApp, VContainer, VBtn, VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib'

   export const plugin = {
     install(app, options) {
       app.use(Vuetify, {
         components: {
           // Vuetify 2.x requires `VApp` to be the root component, so `VApp`
           // needs to be exported unless you prefer the consumer app provided it
           VApp,
           VContainer,

           VBtn,
           VTextField,
         },
         ...options
       })
     }
   }
   ```
5. Run this command to build the library:

   ```
   npm run build
   ```

#### Usage

In `dist/demo.html` from the library build output, load the UMD script (`MyVuetify.umd.js`), which sets a global named `MyVuetify`, containing the exports from the build output (defined earlier in step 4). Also load the styles (`MyVuetify.css`), which contains the CSS for the used Vuetify components.

```html
<script src="./MyVuetify.umd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./MyVuetify.css">
```

Finally, create a `<script>` block that installs the plugin from `MyVuetify.plugin` and initializes the Vue app's `vuetify` with `MyVuetify.vuetify()`:

```html
<script>
Vue.use(MyVuetify.plugin)

new Vue({
  vuetify: MyVuetify.vuetify(/* Vuetify options (e.g., `theme`) */),
})
</script>
```

Here's a complete `dist/demo.html`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="./MyVuetify.umd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./MyVuetify.css">

<v-app id="app">
  <v-container>
    <form @submit.prevent="greet">
      <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name"></v-text-field>
      <v-btn type="submit">Greet</v-btn>
    </form>
  </v-container>
</v-app>

<script>
Vue.use(MyVuetify.plugin)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: MyVuetify.vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    name: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    greet() {
      alert(`Hi ${this.name.trim() || 'there'}!`)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vuetify-component-lib-demo)

Comment: This is really great, thank you for the detailed example. I didn't realize that I had to tell the build that I was creating a library.